# Is it possible to style <input type="file"> with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Is possible to make stylish for browse button `<input type="file" />` using CSS and Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by browse button?

Comment: When the question's tags convey more information than the question itself you know the OP is too vague...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How apply CSS to browse button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365431/how-apply-css-to-browse-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the `<input type="file">` browse button, see this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html