# How apply CSS to browse button

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<input type="file" />` in my webpage. I've different CSS classes for button and other controls. But I'm not able to add any class, style to browse button that appears due to above tag.

Is there any way to change its default appearance?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Doesn't applying a CSS class for that button work?

Comment: How to add class to that button? Actually that button is generated dynamically on browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You could only apply style to the entire `<input />`.

You could use `opacity: 0` CSS hacks to replace it with you favorite image and image:hover.

Keep in mind that `height:` property will not work on Firefox 3.6; You could use `font-size:` to enlarge the height instead.

I have an example made: http://timc.idv.tw/html5-file-upload/ ; inspect the CSS of the 2nd demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the file input directly, but you can indeed give it some faux styling and/or make it invisible but still clickable. There's an article on how to do so at [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="file" />` control is notoriously difficult to style.

[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) are [some](http://shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom) [articles](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html) that can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are also [some nice libraries](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) for styling hard-to-skin form elements. Uniform is nice for selects and upload fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style a file input button with CSS. This is not the only element that you can not style. Some other inputs are not accepting styles. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/Yt4b3/) to see many types of inputs. Based on your browser some inputs renders different. Inputs like range input or date inputs are using OS level UI that is not editable by CSS.

What you can do is hiding the file input and showing another element like a div or another input that is accepting styling like button type input as your file input and trigger trigger click and submit (hitting enter) events on your hided actual file input.

Code example:

HTML

```
<input type="file" />
<label>Select file to upload: <input type="button" /></label>
```

CSS

```
input[type="file"]{visibility:hidden; width:0;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var fileInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')[0],
    fakeFileInput = document.querySelectorAll('label')[0],
    clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click',true,true,document.defaultView,1,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);

fakeFileInput.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   fileInput.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}, false);
```

Look at [fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/CxkD7/)

So answer of you question is: No, unfortionantly you can not style file input BUTTON!

Comment: Browser do not open on Firefox and worked just first time on Chrome.