# how to change Browse button style in fileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, html

For fileUpload control, there is a embeded button "Browse" button for looking file on local machine.

Is it possible to change the style of this button? for example apply style sheet on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How apply CSS to browse button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365431/how-apply-css-to-browse-button)

Comment: It's not possible to control the style of a file input browse button to a large extent.

Answer (score 1):

It works, with the help of CSS and programming techniques; the way i always used to follow is as follows:

```
<style>
 .mainDiv {
    position:relative; height:auto; width:300px;
 }

 #brwShow {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:right;
    top: 0px;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
    background:#F60;
    height:26px;
    width:240px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:26px;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:10px;
 }

 #brwField {
    width:155px;
    height:26px;
    margin-right:85px;
    font-size:16px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
 }

 #hideBrowse {
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
    height:26px;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
 }
 .textUpload {
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFF;
    left: 183px;
    top: 3px;
    line-height:20px;
    z-index:10001;
 }
</style>
```

And the html is

```
 <div class="mainDiv">
  <input type="file" size="24" id="hideBrowse" onchange="getElementById('FileField').value = getElementById('BrowserHidden').value;" />
  <div id="brwShow"><input type="text" id="brwField" /></div>
  <div class="textUpload">Upload</div>
 </div>
```